# Электронные переводы банковских карт

Tags: android, javax.money

Я хочу реализовать денежные переводы в программе на андроид , с карты на карту MILLIKART.

Пример:

> пользователь @ имеет на своей карте 1000 денежных едениц и хочет перевести эти деньги пользователю #. Пользователь @ заходит в прогу и прописывает данные своей карты, а затем код карты получателя нажимает далее и перевод осуществлён.

Как это можно реализовать для MILLIKART?

Comment: Вероятно через оператора держателя этих карт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо посмотреть на api данных карт. Может они предоставляют эти возможности,которые вам нужны.

Если нет - то лучше на прямую связаться с компаниями,которые эти карты производят и спросить какие возможности они имеют.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601138/money-transfer-via-android-ios-app-using-credit-cards - вот тут человек задавал вопрос по поводу трансфера данных между двумя картами

Comment: Martinez Toni , а как и где считать этот API и каким он должен быть? И что с API дальше делать?

Comment: Martinez Toni, может есть какой нибудь ресурс с инфой на эту тему?Где можно почитать на такую тему?

Comment: @Ильхам обновил

Comment: @Ильхам, приходите в банк владеющий этими картами(судя по гуглу - госбанк туркменистана), встречаетесь с руководством, обсуждаете идею с ними, и случае одобрения - вас отправляют к техперсоналу, который дает вам готовую документацию, адрес. и реквизиты доступа к их API, либо совместно с вами работают над проектом и этот самый API попутно создают..

Comment: Martinez Toni , погуглив нашел на GitHub кое какой пример . https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/The-Hasanov/millikart/blob/master/readme.md&ved=2ahUKEwjGqqfvnMXgAhVRKuwKHQXWAA4QFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3PkJhSmQGMDHcQlr86DClj

Comment: Sergey Rufanov  ,да , верно , это Туркменистан. Просто я не знаю как отреагируют в банке на такое предложение. Так как только что эта функция стала доступна в самом банкомате а раньшефункция была но неработала.

Comment: @Ильхам либо согласятся либо откажут. Все просто)

Comment: Martinez Toni,  Всё просто но всё же,  могу ли я реализовать это без сотрудничества с банком или это невозможно?

Comment: @Ильхам поищите апи. Если найдете - то можете.